# Can the pocket dimension created by the mirror of life trapping be returned to by using the Gate spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

A wizard needs a few decades to think over a problem, and decides to do so in his [mirror of life trapping](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Mirror%20of%20Life%20Trapping#content) to prevent himself from aging. He packs a bag full of writing supplies and a 5000gp diamond, and has a servant activate the mirror to trap the wizard inside. After a few years have past, the wizard realizes he misses his liquor cabinet, and casts [Gate](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Gate#content) to return to his study. After grabbing a couple bottles and regaining his 9th level spell slot (he took too long and the gate had run its duration), he wishes to return to the mirror. Can the wizard recast gate and step back into the mirror, or must he return to the mirror by his servant reactivating the mirror? Does the extra dimensional cell remain in existence when the wizard leaves it, or collapse until the cell is refilled? What if the wizard leaves his notes, are they ejected when the wizard leaves?

If applicable, what other pocket dimension can or cannot be returned too in this way?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate of [Can you plane shift to a pocket dimension?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79645/can-you-plane-shift-to-a-pocket-dimension). Can you clarify why it wouldn't be if you don't agree?

Comment: @NautArch Gate acts differently enough from Plane Shift for this question not to be a duplicate: the latter spell requires an item attuned to said plane/pocket dimension, the first does not.

Comment: @Nautarch as Kaito said, using Gate spell vs using Plane Shift, but also specifically the cells created by the mirror of life trapping.  do all 12 cells exist, even when not filled? or only while a creature resides inside of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to new information gathered from my question [Does Rope Trick create an extradimensional space, or does the space already exist?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176720/60441), a lot of this answer falls apart. I am going to leave the answer as-is, since it has received a few positive votes. I still believe that the wording *implies* that the cells exist, simply because it never says that the cells are created. However, it does not explicitly state either way, so it may be up to the DM to make the decision.

## The cells continue to exist, so there is nothing preventing *Gate* from stepping into the cell.

There are a couple of questions to address here.

### "Can the pocket dimension created by the mirror of life trapping be returned to by using the Gate spell?"

The Mirror of Life Trapping simply states that

> A creature trapped within a cell can escape using magic that permits Planar Travel.

It says nothing about re-entering. This, like you deducted, would probably depend on whether the extradimensional cell exists outside of being occupied. If the space exists, than I see no reason why the *Gate* spell couldn't be used to enter it.

### "Does the extra dimensional cell remain in existence when the wizard leaves it, or collapse until the cell is refilled? What if the wizard leaves his notes, are they ejected when the wizard leaves?"

The wording of Mirror of Life Trapping implies that they continue to exist outside of being occupied:

> Any creature other than you that sees its reflection in the activated mirror ... [will] be trapped, along with anything it is wearing or carrying, in **one of the mirror's twelve extradimensional cells**

If the cells did not already exist, it would probably read something like "An extradimensional cell is created, up to twelve."

If we compare it to the wording of [*Rope Trick*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Rope%20Trick#content), which also uses the term "extradimensional"

> ...an Invisible entrance opens to an extradimensional space **that lasts until the spell ends.**

This explicitly states that the space is created brand-new and is completely destroyed once the spell ends. Since such text does not exist for the Mirror, it's safe to say that they exist, anything left in them (after *Gate*ing out) remains in them, and you can *Gate* back in at any time.